# The difference between ":" and =" in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

In angular 2, I notice there is a few ways to declare variable using `=`, using `:` and `public`.

example:

```
  public heroes = HEROES;
  title = "Tour of Heroes";
  selectedHero: Hero;
```

what is the difference ? is it only about initialized and uninitialized ?

Comment: Angular is just Javascript, so I expect you found the `:` in an object declaration

Comment: I see, well I thought it should be use like this -> `var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};` , but it seems it doesn't need to, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because javascript doesn't have `type checking` meaning you can do `someVar="hello"` and later you can assign a value of another type ,e.g. boolean like `someVar=true`, which is fine in javascript. **Type**script offers type checking capabilities among other features for javascript.This has nothing to do with initialization.

- `=` sets the value of the variable
- `:` sets the type of the variable

In your example:

```
public heroes = HEROES;  // assigns value of HEROES to heroes, heroes now has an inferred type same as the type of HEROES
title = "Tour of Heroes"; // normal assignment with inferred type of 'string'
selectedHero: Hero; // just declares selectedHero with the type 'Hero'
```

You can set a value and type at the same time:

```
title:string = "some text"; // this means, title is of type string and has the value "some text"
```

later if you do,  `title=true` the compiler will give you a warning because you are trying to assign boolean value to a variable with type string.

**Extra** 
You can also set to multiple types instead of just one:

```
title:string|boolean=true; // title is of type either string or boolean
title:"text1"|"text2"|"text3"; // (v1.8 and after) title is of type string and can have only one of the values: "text1","text2" or "text3". in other words enum type 
title:any; // title is of any type.
```

**On function declaration:**

```
someFunction(name:string):boolean{
    // the parameter 'name' is expected to be of type string in the body of this function

    return true; // the return type of the function is expected to be boolean
}
```

**Lambda Expression:**

```
someFunction = (name:string):boolean => {
    // the variable name is expected to be of type string in the body of this function
    return true;
}
```

Further reading:
[Typescript specs for Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3-types)
[Typescript Type System](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html)

Comment: thanks that explain a lot, especially the different with regular javascript.

Comment: You are welcome @whale_steward, I edited my answer with more usage examples.

Comment: @M.M, I was actually assuming it's inside a class. Otherwise, `public/private` will not be used. Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly!?

Answer (score 3):

: define the type of a variable and does not initialize

= initialize a variable and implicitely define its type

public defines a variable as public, i.e.  accessible from outside the class (opposed to private)